# Multilayer Perceptron replaced with Single Layer Perceptron

Tags: math, machine-learning, neural-network, linear-algebra, perceptron

I got a problem in understending the difference between MLP and SLP.

I know that in the first case the MLP has more than one layer (the hidden layers) and that the neurons got a **non linear** activation function, like the logistic function (needed for the gradient descent). But I have read that:

> "if all neurons in an MLP had a linear activation function, the MLP
>   could be replaced by a single layer of perceptrons, which can only
>   solve linearly separable problems"

I don't understand why in the specific case of the XOR, which is not linearly separable, the equivalent MLP is a two layer network, that for every neurons got a linear activation function, like the step function. I understand that I need two line for the separation, but in this case I cannot apply the rule of the previous statment (the replacement of the MLP with the SLP).

Mlp for xor:

http://s17.postimg.org/c7hwv0s8f/xor.png

In the linked image the neurons A B and C have a linear activation function (like the step function)

Xor:
http://s17.postimg.org/n77pkd81b/xor1.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A linear function is `f(x) = a x + b`. If we take another linear function `g(z) = c z + d`, and apply g(f(x)) (which would be the equivalent of feeding the output of one linear layer as the input to the next linear layer) we get `g(f(x)) = c (a x + b) + d = ac x + cb + d = (ac) x + (cb + d)` which is in itself another linear function.

**The step function is not a linear function** - You cannot write it as `a x + b`. That's why a MLP using a step function is strictly more expressive than a single layer perceptron using a step function.